# iOS UIWebView open a link in Safari (in HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have a website requiring a new tab to be opened for a 3rd party service to authenticate, unfortunately in Safari UIWebView (when viewing the site in another app like Instagram for example) this is not allowed.

I'm looking to provide a link to open the site in the system browser if UIWebView is detected (via JavaScript), but can't find any solutions. Have seen `target="_system"` floating around, but is apparently not supported. Any pointers appreciated.

To be extra clear — I need a front-end web (HTML / JavaScript) solution, as this is for a website being viewed in UIWebView, i have no control over the application the site is being viewed in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this may helps you,

You may use SFSafariViewController, When you detected required link in UIWebView
Like This:

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: self.urlString)!)
self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You may present or Push SFSafariViewController, as its ViewController itself. So, user may get back just like we close new tab.

Comment: Thanks, as stated though — I am not developing the application using UIWebView — but the website being viewed in UIWebView, I need a front-end browser solution in HTML or Javascript.